# wicd network manager can'f find my wifi network

Tags: debian, wifimanager

Here is the problem, my wicd network manager which works under my debian box can't find my wifi network SSID, which could find via command "iwlist wlan0 scanning". Have anyone met situation this before?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that wicd is configured to have "wlan0" (or whatever the name of your wlan device is) as the wireless lan adaptor